# Cannot create alias for a script

Tags: macos, terminal, ventura, zsh

I am making an alias for Bazelisk, as I have installed a jailbroken version of brew (edited the code so I did not have to use sudo privileges to install). However, because of that, Bazelisk is not installed properly I am doing this in order to install the TensorFlow_text module, which could not be installed for some reason. However, this time I am so close to successfully installing it. All I need to do now is create an alias for Bazel so the building scripts recognize it. Note that I am not willing to go around changing the code. Here is the line in the `~/.zshrc` file that is not doing what I want it to do:

```
alias bazel='/Users/someone/homebrew/Cellar/bazelisk/1.17.0/bin/bazelisk'
```

And when I try to run Bazel, I get this zsh error:

```
zsh: command not found: bazel
```

Comment: Are you certain that the path is correct?  Try running it from command line first *before* creating the alias.  Also, why not create a symlink instead of an alias?

Comment: I have done that. And it did work @Allan

Comment: Re-source `.zshrc`.  Type `. ~/.zshrc` and then try again.  If that works, then everything is good.  Just close all Terminal windows and try again.

Comment: How did you ensure that the changes you did into your .zshrc, made its way into the shell you were using to test the alias?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here is the line in the ~/.zshrc file that is not doing what I want it to do…

Since you verified that the command and path were valid (per comments), the most likely culprit here is that the `.zshrc` file wasn’t reloaded.  You can do this two ways:

- Direct from the command line by sourcing it:

  ```
  % source ~/.zshrc
     or
  % . ~/.zshrc
  ```
- Close all Terminal Windows and Reopen.  When you reopen Terminal, it will read the `.zshrc` and `.zprofile` files anew.